# Why is the make target up to date even when using .phony?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile that looks like this:

```
RENDER_HTML=jupyter nbconvert --execute --to html
MATE40001_TARGETS=$(wildcard MATE40001/notes/*.ipynb)

.phony: all
all:    MATE40001

.phony: variables
variables:
    @echo MATE40001_TARGETS:
    @echo ${MATE40001_TARGETS} | sed 's/ /\n/' | sed 's/MATE/\tMATE/'

.phony: MATE40001
MATE40001:  ${MATE40001_TARGETS}
    mkdir -p $@/html/
    ${RENDER_HTML} $^
    mv $@/notes/*.html $@/html/

.phony: clean
clean:
    rm -rf */html/ *~ */notes/*.html
```

When I run:

```
make
make clean 
make
make MATE40001
```

I get the following output:

```
...
<normal output>
...
rm -rf */html/ *~ */notes/*.html
make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make: 'MATE40001' is up to date.
```

As far as I understand, `make` is looking for the file MATE40001 which exists as a folder and then stops because there are no updated files. However I do not want this to happen, and I thought that adding `.phony: MATE40001` would stop this problem.

What do I need to add/change to fix this issue?

Comment: Typo: `.phony` --> `.PHONY` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from comment by @G.M.

Use `.PHONY` instead of `.phony`